# How to create menuitem (?) in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just have a quick question on where i can find documentation about a view like this below that i see on a lot of different for example iOS apps:

[image]

Is there a sample project or documentation somewhere on how to implement it in xamarin forms? Perhaps this isn't possible but is there a similiar option out there for Xamarin forms development?

Comment: Do you want popup menu like this or toolbar? If there is only 2 options you might use switch

Comment: I would prefer a popup menu similiar to the image i posted. A switch is also possible of course but i want text on each option

Comment: Why don't you use ContentView? You can then either make it modal or just add to Children on page you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/segmented-controls/). There is no default support for it in Xamarin.Forms, probably because it isn't a control that is common on all three platforms.

There are a few ways about this if you still want to use it. Which basically break down to two scenarios: you either use the real native control and have to create different views for iOS and the other platforms you want to use. Or you simulate the segmented control with for instance the [FreshEssentials](http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshessentials-for-xamarin-forms-the-must-have-nuget-for-forms/) NuGet by Michael Ridland. There are more of them out there.

If you choose the latter implementation will be easy and can be done right from XAML.

If you choose the first option you can either do it with a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) or with the Native Embedding (Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0+) features. I have written a [blogpost](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/embedding-native-controls-in-your-xamarin-forms-app/) about it, but here are the basics. I am assuming you are using XAML to model your interface.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmbedNativeAwesomeness"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:UIKit;assembly=Xamarin.iOS;targetPlatform=iOS"
    x:Class="EmbedNativeAwesomeness.EmbedNativeAwesomenessPage">

<!-- Rest of page here -->
</ContentPage>
```

First add the ios namespace declaration to your page. Notice how it has a `targetPlatform` tag in it, which means this will only be included when the iOS project is targeted.

Now, with the `ios:` prefix you can access all the iOS platform controls directly in Forms, in XAML.

So declaring the Segmented Control would probably be something like: `<ios:UISegmentedControl />` and specifying the right properties to your needs.

There are some drawbacks to this method right now, but I'm sure you can work around it. For more info check my blogpost (and accompanying [sample code](https://github.com/jfversluis/EmbedNativeAwesomeness)) or some more resources [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :) Just what I was looking for. Will check it out straight away